# is server log slow or fast

Tags: performance, logging

when server (apache or nginx) logging http request into the log file, (i.e. append entry at the end), is it slow or fast? when if there is very high volumn traffic, will writing to log file slow down performance?

-------- More ------------
and usually, how many entries can be logged each second?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this subject but it sounds quite expensive, yeah. I'll keep the logs in a buffer and update the file at a certain time, at least during the busiest part of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fast unless you have such an extreme workload that it slows down, in which case you might want to upgrade the disk where the logs are written.

Answer (score 3):

Logging itself will be fast: the data put into the log file will typically be smaller than the data sent back to the browser, plus the hard disk has higher throughput than the network interface.

What may slow down the logging is when you try to do DNS reverse lookups for each IP address, so make sure to turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

I second all answers. Here's an additional thought: if you're concerned about speed, don't use the same *physical* device to do the logging and the serving.

Comment: So.. what you mean is that, I can log in a different server ? or you mean log in different 'mount' device? (e.g. different drive)  sorry.. i may be a little bit confused here. :)

Comment: @sea I think he means a separate physical hard drive.

Comment: Yes. A physical device (i.e. "hard-drive") mounted and pointed to by your Apache configuration. As [Martin indirectly pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717561/is-server-log-slow-or-fast/4717613#4717613), there's little gain, though. Still if you're trying to squeeze the last bit of performance, that might do it.